# pywintypes giving Class not registered error while key exist

Tags: python, windows, com, registry, sapb1

I have a script where I am trying to load a COM object in Python.

```
import win32com.client.CLSIDToClass, pythoncom, pywintypes
import win32com.client.util
from pywintypes import IID
from win32com.client import Dispatch

CLSID = IID('{632F4591-AA62-4219-8FB6-22BCF5F60090}')

pythoncom.new(CLSID)
```

When I run this, I am getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "test.py", line 8, in
>
> pythoncom.new(CLSID)
>
> pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221164, 'Class not registered', None, None)

I have this registry key available and installed as part of SAP DI API setup as I can see and find this ID via regedit. I am able to load other register keys but this along with some other registry keys are not loading.

I have Python 2.7 with required libs for SAP B1 Client and DI API 64 bit installed.

Comment: Is your Python a 32-bit or 64-bit Python? Is the COM object a 32-bit or 64-bit server? If it's a DLL server, then the bitness (32/64) has to match. If it is out of process, it doesn't. My first guess would be that the bitness doesn't match

Comment: I have tried both from Python 32-bit and 64-bit with same result. The application for which COM belongs too is 64 bit. 

The confusing part is the key for this application is installed in path of 32-bit apps. It is SAP DI API / Client package. 

Now I was wondering if it is possible to explicitly ask my python script to load the registry class from specific location. Is it a good idea?

Comment: Does the COM server you are using have a ProgID? Have you tried using it instead of the CLSID. If you are using a CLSID, it has to be for the COM coclass object in the type library and not the CLSID (IID) of the interface.

Comment: I don't see ProgID for this specific id e.g. 632F4591-AA62-4219-8FB6-22BCF5F60090

Here is the screen shot for this key from regedit:
https://ibb.co/ZL9gZTP

Comment: Search the entire registry for the CLSID. If there is a ProgID for it, it should help you find it. I don't recall ever seeing an InprocServer32 registry key with a subkey. Microsoft documents what an InprocServer32 key should look like at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/inprocserver32

Comment: I will go through this documentation. I got this CLSID after I generated Python via makepy.py from the required DLL file for SAPbobsCOM90.dll